# What's the license of MIMIC-III?

Tags: mimic-iii, licensing

What's the license of MIMIC-III, if any?

I could only find the MIMIC II Clinical Database Restricted Data Use Agreement, which I copy below:

> If I am granted access to the MIMIC II Clinical Database, I agree to
>   the terms and conditions below:
>
> 1. I will not attempt to identify any individual referenced in restricted    data from PhysioNet.
> 2. I will exercise all reasonable and prudent care to avoid disclosure of    the identity of any individual referenced in
>      restricted data from PhysioNet    in any publication or other
>      communication.
> 3. I will not share access to restricted data from PhysioNet with anyone    else.
> 4. I will exercise all reasonable and prudent care to maintain the physical    and electronic security of restricted data from PhysioNet.
> 5. If I find information within restricted data from PhysioNet that I    believe might permit identification of any individual, I will
>      report the    location of this information promptly by email to
>      mimic-support@physionet.org, citing the location of the specific
>      information    in question so that it can be investigated and removed
>      if necessary.
> 6. I have requested access to restricted data from PhysioNet for the sole    purpose of lawful use in scientific research, and I will
>      use my privilege of    access, if it is granted, for this purpose and
>      no other.
> 7. I have completed a training program in human research subjects    protections and I am submitting proof of having done so.
> 8. This agreement may be terminated by either party at any time, but my    obligations with respect to restricted data from PhysioNet
>      shall continue    after termination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the new data use agreement for MIMIC-III as of v1.4 (current version at time of writing):

> 1. I will not attempt to identify any individual or institution referenced in PhysioNet restricted data.
> 2. I will exercise all reasonable and prudent care to avoid disclosure of the identity of any individual or institution referenced in PhysioNet restricted data in any publication or other communication.
> 3. I will not share access to PhysioNet restricted data with anyone else.
> 4. I will exercise all reasonable and prudent care to maintain the physical and electronic security of PhysioNet restricted data.
> 5. If I find information within PhysioNet restricted data that I believe might permit identification of any individual or institution, I will report the location of this information promptly by email to PHI-report@physionet.org, citing the location of the specific information in question so that it can be investigated and removed if necessary.
> 6. I have requested access to PhysioNet restricted data for the sole purpose of lawful use in scientific research, and I will use my privilege of access, if it is granted, for this purpose and no other.
> 7. I have completed a training program in human research subject protections and HIPAA regulations, and I am submitting proof of having done so.
> 8. I will indicate the general purpose for which I intend to use the database in my application.
> 9. If I openly disseminate my results, I will also contribute the code used to produce those results to a repository that is open to the research community.
> 10. This agreement may be terminated by either party at any time, but my obligations with respect to restricted data from PhysioNet shall continue after termination.